# Convert nvarchar to datetime - format 19/02/2019 12.00.00 AM

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert `19/02/2019 12.00.00 AM` format to datetime in a stored procedure SQL Sercver 2012.

I tried

```
select cast('19/02/2019 12.00.00 AM' as datetime)
```

and

```
select convert(datetime, '19/02/2019 12.00.00 AM', 108)
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 2):

You need to firstly replace the "." with ":" because no SQL Server time format works with ".". Then you need to use the correct format, 108 is a time only format, 103 is what you are looking for.

```
select convert(datetime, replace('19/02/2019 12.00.00 AM', '.', ':'), 103)
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

You should have the VARCHAR literal in proper format. As other answers suggest, you can go for replace. I would prefer to represent in the below way, as it is more clear. The below one works:

```
Select convert(datetime, '19/02/2019 12:00:00 AM', 103)
```

I am suggesting to you to follow the ISO 8601 standard for datetime literals. It will take care in representing the datetime in the same way, irrespective of locale. Read more on [datetime datetype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). I am putting content about ISO 8601 below for your reference.

> ISO 8601  Description YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]
>
> YYYYMMDD[ hh:mm:ss[.mmm]] Examples:
>
> 1) 2004-05-23T14:25:10
>
> 2) 2004-05-23T14:25:10.487
>
> To use the ISO 8601 format, you must specify each element in the
>   format, including the T, the colons (:), and the period (.) that are
>   shown in the format.
>
> The brackets indicate that the fraction of second component is
>   optional. The time component is specified in the 24-hour format.
>
> The T indicates the start of the time part of the datetime value.
>
> The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an
>   international standard with unambiguous specification. Also, this
>   format isn't affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE setting.

Comment: How does that solve the OP's problem? Its not in the format you're suggesting.

Comment: I am suggesting him to represent in the right way. Yes. I could have used replace. I am suggesting him for right representation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with replacing (.) with (:)

```
SELECT convert(datetime,REPLACE('19/02/2019 12.00.00 AM','.',':'),    103)
```